# Keeping program alive on a godaddy server

Tags: linux, server, daemon, shared-hosting

I need to keep my ruby server and redis database online all the time on this server, but them always end up receiving a SIGTERM and closing after some hours. Already tried running them with bg and leaving the terminal with exit, adding to crontab but none seems to really work. I'm trying to turn them into daemons, but don't know how, as systemctl, and other commands are not found on this server terminal. I'm not the root.

Long story short: I need to keep a program running forever in machine I don't have root or systemctl

Some command runs:

systemctl:

```
$ systemctl
-bash: systemctl: command not found
```

uname:

```
$ uname -or
4.18.0-477.15.1.lve.2.el8.x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

help:

```
$ help
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
.
.
.
```

redis crash:

```
$ redis-server
.
.
.
799990:signal-handler (1696324203) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
799990:M 03 Oct 2023 02:10:03.735 * User requested shutdown...
799990:M 03 Oct 2023 02:10:03.735 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
799990:M 03 Oct 2023 02:10:03.741 * DB saved on disk
799990:M 03 Oct 2023 02:10:03.741 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
```

ruby crash:

```
$ ruby main.rb
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2023-10-03 02:10:04] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2023-10-03 02:10:04] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```